# how to extend root (/) partition by freeing ext4 partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted, ext4

My root (/) partition is full and i want to extend my root file system by freeing extra memory present in other partition which is ext4.

How to free some space with ext4 allocation and how to extend that freed memory to root(/) part.?

Here is image showned by gparted.
[image](http://s11.postimg.org/l2grpbdkz/gpartd.png)

And here is the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        19G   15G  2.9G  84% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1.1M  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  416K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6       662G  132G  497G  21% /home
```

Please guide in doing this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Resize sda6, then move it to the right ( this will take a very long time, and if you lose power in the middle your data is lost, so make sure you have an updated backup ), then move sda5 to the right, then move the start of sda2 to the right, and finally you will have free space following sda1 that you can expand it into.

To manipulate these partitions requires that they not be mounted at the time, so you will have to boot from a cd instead of that disk.

Comment: beginner here. can you be little more explain your answer? plz

Comment: when i select resize/move (=>) it doesn't activate "resize" button.

Comment: check image http://s18.postimg.org/xqh0tmp6h/rsz.png

Comment: you have to click and drag.  Drag to the left: shrink. drag to the right, extend.